# ¿Puedo mandar a ejecutar un stored procedure desde un trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure, trigger

De ser asi podrian publicar un ejemplo para ver la sintaxis correcta? 
digamos que quiero ejecutar el stored procedure con nombre: TEST1

Comment: De poder...se puede. Un simple `CALL sp_blabla(NEW.valor)` dentro del trigger debería funcionar. Ahora, de ser algo recomendado...pues no, ojalá puedas ver una forma de no tener que ejecutar un sp por cada valor afectado de la tabla

Answer (score -1):

Puedes intentar con esto:

```
create trigger TEST1 before insert 
on tuTabla 
for each row 
call tuStoresProcedure;
```

Debes verificar si ocupas que se ejecute antes o después de tu `insert`. Espero solucione tu problema. Saludos.